# seo friendly url IIS

Tags: iis

I have a very big problem I tried seo friendly url a few days ago and it will work on local but when I put my project on iis it shows:

> 404 error

My route is:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                   "Slug", // Route name
                   "{slug}/{cat}/{langx},{longi}", // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "Demo", action = "Index"} // Parameter 

defaults
           );
```

My redirection method is:

```
window.location.href=""+add+"/"+category+"/"+lang+","+longit+"";
```

My ActionFilterAttribute before the execution of method which is:

```
public class SlugToIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    { 
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {               
            var slug = filterContext.RouteData.Values["slug"] as string;
            var cat = filterContext.RouteData.Values["cat"] as string;
            var latitude = filterContext.RouteData.Values["langx"] as string;
            var longitute = filterContext.RouteData.Values["longi"] as string;
            var category = "";
            switch (cat)
            {
                case "Resturant":
                    category = "1";
                    break;
                case "Health and Beauty":
                     category = "2";
                    break;
                case "Travel":
                    category = "3";
                    break;
                case "Free Deal":
                     category = "4";
                    break;
                case "Activity and hobbies":
                     category = "5";
                    break;
                case "Miscellaneous":
                     category = "6";
                    break;
                case "Grocery":
                     category = "7";
                    break;
                default:
                     category="1";
                    break;

            }


                string strg=slug.Replace("-",",");
                if (latitude != null)
                {
                    string lat = latitude.Replace("-", ".");
                    if (longitute != null)
                    {
                        string log = longitute.Replace("-", ".");
                        //SlugIds.TryGetValue(slug, out id);

                        filterContext.ActionParameters["ULat1"] = lat;
                        filterContext.ActionParameters["ULong1"] = log;
                    }
                }
                filterContext.ActionParameters["address1"] = slug;
                filterContext.ActionParameters["UMainCat1"] = category;

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: it shows *404* on which url? you need to tell us how you access the actions, and how you deploy the project

Comment: on this url   window.location.href=""+add+"/"+category+"/"+lang+","+longit+""; which is converted as  abc/xyz/2,1